# Apply relative path to a given path in Java

Tags: java, filepath, relative-path

Given an absolute path to a directory: pathA, and a relative path pathB, find the absolute path of pathB from pathA.

```
public String applyPath(String pathA, String pathB) { ...

assertEquals("/a/b/file.txt", applyPath("/a/b/c/d", "../../file.txt"));

assertEquals("/a/b/c/file.txt", applyPath("/a/b/c", "./file.txt"));
```

How would i write such a function using java libraries preferably and not do string manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Java [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) and it's `resolve` method like

```
Paths.get(pathA).resolve(pathB);
```

Comment: Thank you, I additionally used canonical paths to get it in the desired format: `new File(Paths.get(pathA).resolve(pathB).toUri()).getCanonicalPath()`

Comment: @iluvAS, you don't need to create a File object for that. Check `Path::normalize()` and `Path::toAbsolutePath()`.